# What memory Scanners/Editors are available?

Tags: software-recommendation

Are there memory scanners/editors for Ubuntu (like CheatEngine for Windows)?
I'm aware of scanmem, but I'm thinking about something with a GUI and that lets me visualize the memory segment.

Comment: I made this question almost 6 months ago! Why was it edited right now? The changes aren't even worth it... With all due respect, I think moderators at Stackoverflow are just abusing their right to edit questions. Changing 'ubuntu' to 'Ubuntu' on a dead thread... really?

Comment: Well, you should get used to the idea that you don't own your question. And, in my opinion, the edit was a pretty good one. It made the question clearer and more likely to come up in a relevant search, and corrected the name of the utility.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install gameconqueror`

[Gameconqueror](https://github.com/scanmem/scanmem)

```
Description-en: GUI for scanmem, a game hacking tool
 Scanmem is a simple interactive debugging utility for Linux, used to locate
 the address of a variable in a running process. This can be used for the
 analysis or modification of a hostile process on a compromised machine, for
 reverse engineering, or as a "pokefinder" to cheat at video games.
 .
 GameConqueror is a GUI for scanmem, aims to provide more features than
 scanmem, and CheatEngline-alike user-friendly interface.
Homepage: https://github.com/scanmem/scanmem
```